# How does jQuery distinguish between $() and $.method calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking at the fallowing structure of an older jQuery version:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

    var jQuery = (function() {

        var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
            return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
        };

        jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
            init: function( selector, context ) {
                // ...
                return this;
            }
            // jQuery API methods
        }

        // Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation
        jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;

        return (window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery);

    })();

})(window);
```

it is quite easy to understand that:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    init: function( selector, context ) {
        return this;
    }
}
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

is the one section that fires when jQuery is called with normal usage as for example

```
$('p')
```

or

```
jQuery('p')
```

it is really not clear how is it possible to call API methods with the form `$.ajax()` or `$.isArray()` and where would you place, lets say, a custom method within the listed code and call it with $.myCustomMethod(). 
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: It’s actually very easy… just consider this hint: every function is also a normal object in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is: `$` has properties, those properties can be methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write yourself a function:

```
function something(n) {
  return n + 1;
}
```

and call it:

```
var x = something(0);
```

You can also attach properties to the function, because it's an object:

```
something.else = function(n) {
  return n - 1;
};
```

You can then call that function via the property reference:

```
var y = something.else(0);
```

The jQuery library uses the global jQuery object (usually referred to as `$`) as a place to put a collection of functions that are generally useful but which don't have any implicit relationship to a collection of elements or objects the what that the various jQuery "methods" do. An obvious example is `$.ajax()`, which is super-useful but which really doesn't have anything to do with the DOM.

By keeping all those functions as properties of `$`, the library avoids "polluting" the global address space.

Comment: Nice explanation.  Clear and easy to follow

Comment: I've read your answer update later. Thank you for the further explanation.

Comment: @Vincent you can add your own functions to `$` - just do something like `$.vincent = function(x, y, z) { ... };`. It's not a bad way of managing your own global functions when you're using jQuery anyway.